# Typescript imporing/referencing interfaces

Tags: typescript

If there is a lib that provides some Interface. I export it

some-lib/index.ts:

```
export interface Something {...}
```

User would be able to import it

app.ts:

```
import {Something} from 'some-lib'
```

So my questions are:

1) Does lib author always should export interfaces that are supposed to be used by lib users?
2) What about `/// <refference...` API, is it obsolete in TS 2.0?

Comment: 1) Yes or it will not be available outside of the module 2) No typings are still around but you can get around using triple slash reference directives using a type manager like tsd or typings or by including all of your typings files in your compilation as well. Version 2.0 will use npm for typings I believe.

Comment: Thanks) you could make an answer, not a comment

Comment: and one more issue: with reference you could include needed d.ts file and not export the interface, so no need to export